# Reset variable value every 60 seconds in infinite loop

Tags: c++, timer

I am doing a project which requires resetting a variable every `1 Minute` without pausing an `infinite loop`.

**For example:**

```
int temp = 0;

while(true){

temp ++;

//After 60 Seconds
call_to_a_function(temp);
temp = 0;

}
```

How can I achieve this in `C++`?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Timers are platform dependent (If you don't want to use `boost::chrono` or some similar library). Which platform are you on?

Comment: Windows 10  - Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    atomic_int  temp;

    std::thread t( [&temp]()
                  {

                      while( temp!= -1){
                          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
                          temp=0;
                      }
                  });


    while ( true )
    {
        temp < INT_MAX ? temp++ : 0;
        cout << temp << endl;
    }
    // do some stuff
    // when program needs to exit, do this to avoid a crash

    temp = -1; // t will exit the loop
    t.join();  // wait until t finishes running
```

While loops with sleep might get optimized away.

Comment: I see I posted something a bit different :)

Comment: I just tried it now, but it causes the program to close suddenly immediately after running.

Comment: Working for me, did you use atomic_int? What is the error on the debugger?

Comment: `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD6A77EA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Fatal program exit requested.`

Comment: Maybe your int is overflowing? 60 seconds is a long time to increment

Comment: No, I have tried 10 seconds and I tried your last update for the code and it still crashes.

Comment: can you explain why you made this condition? `while( temp!= -1)` ?

Comment: To allow exiting  program without the thread crashing. To exit one would call t.join() then set temp to -1 to cause the thread loop to exit